# json encode error in php

Tags: php, json, encoding

I am new to PHP... I have been trying to encode the values retrieved from a MySQL database in JSON and then display the results on a browser..

#### `mysqlcn.php`

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","chetan");
mysql_select_db("db1");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE birthyear>'".$_REQUEST['year']."'");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
$output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
mysql_close();
```

When I try to run it in a browser using address `http://localhost/mysqlcn.php`, I get this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0 
Times New Roman;}{\f1\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}} {\*\generator Msftedit 
5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sb100\sa100\f0\fs24\par \par \f1\fs20\par
\par }
```

I am currently using WAMP server with PHP 5.3.0

#### SQL schema

```
CREATE TABLE people (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
name VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
sex BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
birthyear INT NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Use the `application/json` header when you're outputting `JSON` to the page.

Comment: That's not the output this script could generate by itself. Did you try not using Internet Explorer?

Comment: @russell dias...could u plzzz elaborate ur point by giving an example..

Comment: @chetan: `header("application/json");` followed by your json encoded data.

Comment: yes i tried this...still not showing the output

Answer (score 2):

Your output appears to be RTF. Most likely, you have some code which is converting it from HTML to RTF.

Comment: yup u were correct...i then wrote the program in notepad++ and saved it...on running the program apache server crashed....dont know why???

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wish to use JSON to do the display of your database?

PHP can handle this on its own just fine, unless you have a specific reason.

Comment: actually i am developing an android application where the client retrieves the data from server...i will be parsing data using json...